# Y axis scale is not displaying

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am plotting a bar chart using seaborn and the y-axis scale is not displaying.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set_theme(style="white", context="talk")
rs = np.random.RandomState(8)

# Set up the matplotlib figure
f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(7, 5), sharex=True)

# Generate some sequential data
x = np.array(list("ABCDEFGHIJ"))
y1 = np.arange(1, 11)
sns.barplot(x=x, y=y1, palette="rocket", ax=ax1)
ax1.axhline(0, color="k", clip_on=False)
ax1.set_yticks(y1)
ax1.set_ylabel("Sequential")

# Center the data to make it diverging
y2 = y1 - 5.5
sns.barplot(x=x, y=y2, palette="vlag", ax=ax2)
ax2.axhline(0, color="k", clip_on=False)
ax2.set_yticks(y2)
ax2.set_ylabel("Diverging")

# Randomly reorder the data to make it qualitative
y3 = rs.choice(y1, len(y1), replace=False)
sns.barplot(x=x, y=y3, palette="deep", ax=ax3)
ax3.axhline(0, color="k", clip_on=False)
ax3.set_yticks(y3)
ax3.set_ylabel("Qualitative")

# Finalize the plot
sns.despine(bottom=True)
plt.setp(f.axes, yticks=[])
plt.tight_layout(h_pad=2)
```

I tried adding `set_yticks`, but it is not showing the y scale (though the y-axis label is showing).

How do I get the y-axis scale added to the plot?

Comment: What are you referring to when you say the y-axis "scale"? (Also, there is no reason to make `x` a numpy array since numpy doesn't work well with strings. Instead, just use a regular python list.)

Comment: Why are you calling `plt.setp(f.axes, yticks=[])`?  This removes the y ticks, which I suppose you refer to as "scale".  Did you try removing that call?

Comment: @JohanC, it works when removing but the scale is not in proper order, but when i add `plt.setp(f.axes, yticks=[0, 1])` it shows the start and end value of the y scale, i didnt notice this statement before, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Is your question now solved? In that case, please either accept an answer (even if you create a new answer yourself) or delete the post (in case it probably won't help people who encounter the same problem in the future). If your question isn't solved, can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76696975/edit) your post and add additional information?

Comment: Remove `plt.setp(f.axes, yticks=[])`, `ax1.set_yticks(y1)`, `ax2.set_yticks(y2)`, and `ax3.set_yticks(y3)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `axis.set_yticklabels(y1)` to display the y-axis scale on your bar chart

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set_theme(style="white", context="talk")
rs = np.random.RandomState(8)

# Set up the matplotlib figure
f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(7, 5), sharex=True)

# Generate some sequential data
x = np.array(list("ABCDEFGHIJ"))
y1 = np.arange(1, 11)
sns.barplot(x=x, y=y1, palette="rocket", ax=ax1)
ax1.axhline(0, color="k", clip_on=False)
ax1.set_yticks(y1)
ax1.set_yticklabels(y1)
ax1.set_ylabel("Sequential")

# Center the data to make it diverging
y2 = y1 - 5.5
sns.barplot(x=x, y=y2, palette="vlag", ax=ax2)
ax2.axhline(0, color="k", clip_on=False)
ax2.set_yticks(y2)
ax2.set_yticklabels(y2)
ax2.set_ylabel("Diverging")

# Randomly reorder the data to make it qualitative
y3 = rs.choice(y1, len(y1), replace=False)
sns.barplot(x=x, y=y3, palette="deep", ax=ax3)
ax3.axhline(0, color="k", clip_on=False)
ax3.set_yticks(y3)
ax3.set_yticklabels(y3)
ax3.set_ylabel("Qualitative")

# Finalize the plot
sns.despine(bottom=True)
plt.setp(f.axes, yticks=[])
plt.tight_layout(h_pad=2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: For the future, you should save matplotlib figures using the `savefig` function (in this case, `plt.savefig`) rather than taking a screenshot of the figure. Especially when you have things in the background that would distract from what is important. (I've already edited your answer to replace the image.)

Comment: still, the y axis scale is not showing, in the above image also the y-axis scale is not there, only the y axis scale is printed